# How to print into a csv from Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am using this command to get all of the child folders and child-child folders and so on.

```
Get-ChildItem -dir S:\WGroups -Recurse.
```

But what I would like to do is print it either into a csv or a txt file and was wonder what the best way to do that?

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve].

Comment: see `Export-Csv` or `Out-File`

Comment: See Get-Help [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Export-Csv?view=powershell-5.1) or follow the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -dir S:\WGroups -Recurse | export-csv -Path $env:userprofile\documents\S_wgroups.csv
```

There are a number of fields you may not want, so filtering it to just what you need may be important if you're attempting to process in an automated fashion.

Comment: How would I go about doing only certain columns?

Comment: @JohnWozniak insert a [Select-Object](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object?view=powershell-5.1) specifying the `-Property` you want, see `gci|Get-Member` for a list of available properties.